# How to Find Control in Datalist1?

Tags: asp.net

Hi can anybody tell how i can find a DataList which is inside the DataList control?Its giving the Error Object not set to an Instance.

i am finding the control this way :

DataList dl =((DataList) (DataList1.FindControl("DataList2")));

is it the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends when you want to find the control and which control. If you just want to get all of them you loop through the DataList Items like below. Say you want to access a CheckBox inside a DataList.

```
foreach (DataListItem item in DataList1.Items)
{
  if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
  {
     CheckBox chb=(CheckBox) item.FindControl("CheckBox1");
     if (chb!= null)
     {
        //you can access chb.Checked value
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is DataList2 directly inside DataList1 or is it inside a child component of DataList1?

The `FindControl` method does not do a deep search for controls.

I wrote a method to do this a while ago, I'll post it here incase it's of use:

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> 
                               GetDeepControlsByType<T>(this Control control)
    {
        foreach(Control c in control.Controls)
        {
            if (c is T)
            {
                yield return c;
            }

            if(c.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var x in c.GetDeepControlsByType<T>())
                {
                  yield return x;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you plz tell me what is GetDeepControlsByType is it any Interface or method m confuse

Comment: That looks like a lot of looping.  If the controls are nested several layers deep then you would iterate over the same child control several times.  Looks like it might be quicker to do this without recursion and then you only create one IEnumerable.